# How do i display js objects in html with a button

Tags: javascript, html, methods, javascript-objects

Im currently trying to display my objects & methods in html. My goal is to have 2 buttons in html (info vacc1, info vacc2, that print the information of my objects. My goal is to output it just below my button

Here my js code:

```
function myVaccines(companyName, vaccName, Type, numberOfShots, doesNotContain){
    this.companyName = companyName;
    this.vaccName = vaccName;
    this.Type = Type;
    this.numberOfShots = numberOfShots;
    this.doesNotContain = doesNotContain;
}

var vacc1 = Vacc("Pfizer-BioNTech","BNT162b2","mRNA","2 shots, 21 days apart","Eggs, Preservatives, Latex");
var vacc2 = Vacc("Moderna","mRNA-1273","mRNA","2shots, 28 days apart","Eggs, Preservatives, Latex",)
```

Here my html: (dont know what to put here exactly yet)

```
<button onclick="myVaccines(vacc1)">
        Information Vaccine 1
</button>
    <p>Output1?</p>
    
<button onclick="myVaccines(vacc2)">
        Information Vaccine 2
</button>
    <p>Output2?</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used here JavaScript classes as I would recommend for this case.
Inside it define a function which displays the propertys of your object similar like a `toString()` method in Java.

```
display() {
    return this.companyName + " " + this.vaccName + " " + this.Type + " " + this.numberOfShots + " " + this.doesNotContain;
  }
```

Give your buttons ids and define an eventListener for each button to listen when it will clicked.

`document.getElementById("first").addEventListener('click', function() {`

onclick call the display() function of the object and display the content in the output paragraph

```js
class Vaccines {
  constructor(companyName, vaccName, Type, numberOfShots, doesNotContain) {
    this.companyName = companyName,
      this.vaccName = vaccName,
      this.Type = Type,
      this.numberOfShots = numberOfShots,
      this.doesNotContain = doesNotContain
  }

  display() {
    return this.companyName + " " + this.vaccName + " " + this.Type + " " + this.numberOfShots + " " + this.doesNotContain;
  }
}

var vacc1 = new Vaccines("Pfizer-BioNTech", "BNT162b2", "mRNA", "2 shots, 21 days apart", "Eggs, Preservatives, Latex");

var vacc2 = new Vaccines("Moderna", "mRNA-1273", "mRNA", "2shots, 28 days apart", "Eggs, Preservatives, Latex", )




document.getElementById("first").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = vacc1.display();
});

document.getElementById("second").addEventListener('click', function() {
  document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML = vacc2.display();
});
```

```html
<button id="first">
        Information Vaccine 1
</button>
<p id="out1">Output1?</p>

<button id="second">
        Information Vaccine 2
</button>
<p id="out2">Output2?</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could modify the code a little so that `var vacc1` and `var vacc2` are arrays used as input and use the `splat` operator when calling the function that prints out the content

```js
function myVaccines(companyName, vaccName, Type, numberOfShots, doesNotContain){
    let args=arguments;
    printout(event,...args)
}

const printout=function(e,args){
    e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent=args.join(',')
}

var vacc1 = ["Pfizer-BioNTech","BNT162b2","mRNA","2 shots, 21 days apart","Eggs, Preservatives, Latex"];
var vacc2 = ["Moderna","mRNA-1273","mRNA","2shots, 28 days apart","Eggs, Preservatives, Latex"];
```

```html
<button onclick="myVaccines(vacc1)">Information Vaccine 1</button>
<p></p>
    
<button onclick="myVaccines(vacc2)">Information Vaccine 2</button>
<p></p>
```

A slightly different version with an `Object literal` as input so each printed item is assigned a key ( as from original code perhaps )

```js
function myVaccines(companyName, vaccName, Type, numberOfShots, doesNotContain){
    let args=arguments;
    printout(event,...args)
}

const printout=function(e,args){
    e.target.nextElementSibling.textContent=Object.keys(args).map(key=>{
        return [key,args[key]].join(':')
    }).join( ', ' )
}

var vacc1={
    companyName:'Pfizer-BioNTech',
    vaccName:'BNT162b2',
    Type:'mRNA',
    numberOfShots:'2 shots, 21 days apart',
    doesNotContain:'Eggs, Preservatives, Latex'
}
var vacc2={
    companyName:'Moderna',
    vaccName:'mRNA-1273',
    Type:'mRNA',
    numberOfShots:'2shots, 28 days apart',
    doesNotContain:'Eggs, Preservatives, Latex'
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myVaccines(vacc1)">Information Vaccine 1</button>
<p></p>
    
<button onclick="myVaccines(vacc2)">Information Vaccine 2</button>
<p></p>
```